# How do I initialize a semantic-ui click event in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, semantic-ui

I'm very new to meteor/semantic/javascript in general  so I apologize if this question seems a little to rushed, but I seriously cannot figure this out.

An example of a click event I am trying to initialize, I have a semantic-ui dropdown menu. With what I have now, I get this error:

> => Meteor server restarted
>   Errors prevented startup:
>
> While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
>   client/main.js:18:4: Unexpected token (18:4)
>
> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Here's what I have, I know it's pretty messy. I'll work on that later.

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import '/main.html';
import '/templates/cards.html';
import '../lib/collections.js';


Template.cards.helpers({
  cards: function() {
    return Cards.find();
  }
});

Template.card.events({
  $('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
});
```

```html
<template name="card">
    <div class="three wide column">
      <div class="ui cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        {{header}}
          <div class="ui dropdown right floated">
            <i class=" small grey ellipsis vertical icon"></i>
              <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Edit</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        {{desc}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="extra content">
        <button class="ui fluid blue icon button"><i class="map icon"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Comment: Okay, what I've figured out is that it works when I put semantic's initializing code into a script tag. Would be nice if it would work in a separate file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up with `Template.card.events`, you don't need it at all here.

It should be like this instead:

```
Template.card.onCreated(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: Aha! That worked, thank you! I guess I'll have to go read up more on Blaze then.

Comment: Actually for some reason now it stopped working, I don't know when that happened, but I fixed it by changing it to 'onCreated' instead of 'onCreate'. It was giving me an error saying it was not a function.

Comment: Okay... Now the onCreated fix isn't working. I'm really struggling here.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be `onCreated` of course. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Don't forget that `onCreated` is called just once, when template is created. You would want to use `onRendered` — it's called every time template is rendered. You could also add `Meteor.setTimeout ..., 50` to this dropdown initialization in order to give template some time to render.